# Variance of $\hat{\beta}$ when assuming heteroskedastic error terms

Tags: regression, least-squares, asymptotics

I am wondering why, when we are assuming heteroskedastic error terms:

$Var(\hat{\beta}|X) = (X'X)^{-1}X'E[\varepsilon \varepsilon'|X] X(X'X)^{-1}$

simplifies to

$Var(\hat{\beta}|X) = (\sum{x_ix_i'})^{-1}(\sum \varepsilon_i^2 x_ix_i')(\sum{x_ix_i'})^{-1}$

and not

$Var(\hat{\beta}|X) = (\sum{x_ix_i'})^{-1}(\sum \sigma_i^2 x_ix_i')(\sum{x_ix_i'})^{-1}$

The main difference being the $\varepsilon_i^2$ in the second equation vs. $\sigma_i^2$ in the third one.

Because $E[\varepsilon \varepsilon'|X]$ gives a matrix with $\sigma_i^2$'s on the diagonal.

Comment: Under what condition such that (1) can be simplified into (2)?

Comment: I guess that is also a part of my question. It may have been an error along the way, but it was in my notes so I am thinking that maybe there is an error in my notes.

Comment: If I do this, I will simplify (1) to (3) directly. Last sentence $E(\epsilon_i\epsilon_j) = 0 $ for $i \ne j$ based on the assumption of independence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answer mentioned, there is obviously some confusion here. What happens is that

$$Var(\hat{\beta}|X) = (X'X)^{-1}X'E[\varepsilon \varepsilon'|X] X(X'X)^{-1}$$

*equals*

$$(\sum{x_ix_i'})^{-1}(\sum \sigma_i^2 x_ix_i')(\sum{x_ix_i'})^{-1}$$

and is *consistently estimated* by

$$(\sum{x_ix_i'})^{-1}(\sum \hat \varepsilon_i^2 x_ix_i')(\sum{x_ix_i'})^{-1}$$

where we have used the residuals, and this is the celebrated result in **White, H. (1980). A heteroskedasticity-consistent covariance matrix estimator and a direct test for heteroskedasticity.**

Comment: AHA!! This is where the confusion is coming from. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Equation (1) does not simplify to equation (2):** Since $\varepsilon$ is a random vector, taking the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}(\varepsilon \varepsilon ' | X)$ must give you something that is **not** a function of $\varepsilon$.  The right-hand-side of equation (2) depends on $\varepsilon$ and is therefore a random variable, so it is obviously wrong.